# Reformat php array - json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php array that outputs a json like this:

```
"extraDetails":[
{
"basic":{
"0":{
"id":"101"
},
"1":{
"details":"176381954"
},
"16":{
"birth_date":"1\/15\/1973"
}
]
```

There are multiple headings like extraDetails. the problem is, I want everything to move one up that has a number. Like so: Basically I want to remove the 0, 1, and 16 and whatever arbitrary number comes from the json.

```
"extraDetails":[
{
"basic":{
"id":"101"
"idTest":"101"
"idTest2":"101"
},
"details":"176381954"
"MoreDetails":"176381954"
},
"birth_date":"1\/15\/1973"
}
]
```

UPDATE: This is the array:

```
array(1) {
basic info=>
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=> string(7) "1798919"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) { ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(9) "164315268"
  }
  [16]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(9) "2/15/1977"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(5) "White"
  }
  [20]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=> string(2) "40"
  }
```

UPDATE: This is what I want it to ideally look like:

```
array(1) {
basic info=>
array(16) {
 array(1) {
    ["id"]=> string(7) "1798919"
  }
    array(1) { ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(9) "164315268"
  }
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(9) "2/15/1977"
  }
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=>
    string(5) "White"
  }
  array(1) {
    ["Somevalue"]=> string(2) "40"
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code which generates the array?

Comment: Hi. I don't have it, I only get a json feed. From that I reconvert it to an array

Comment: So show the PHP array and how you want it to look, that's easier than changing the JSON.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Updated

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object, have a read and see what you think.

Comment: Hi @NigelRen That appears to be the reason its happening. But it doesn't provide a solution to remove it or reverse it.

Comment: Try `$array['basic info'] = array_values($array['basic info']);`

Comment: Hi. I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501154/php-reindexing-nested-array-recursively

Comment: Given your data that's not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The keys are unique in the JSON but not in the PHP array so I'll assume that is copy paste issue or something.  If the indexes are unique then just merge them (PHP >= 5.6.0):

```
$array['basic info'] = array_merge(...$array['basic info']);
```

For older versions:

```
$array['basic info'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array['basic info']);
```

Comment: Its a copy paste issue. the indexes are also not unique. This json has over 200 headers and 6000 possible fields, no way to write it out. Has to be a variable with a foreach loop to just remove the index-counter (I assume) in the front.

Comment: Did this work?  You have to adjust based on whether it's really `basic` or `basic info` or whatever. Lot's of discrepancies.